# antiword "The combination PDF and UTF-8 is not supported"

Tags: pdf, microsoft-word

I'm trying to convert a .doc file to pdf with antiword:

```
antiword -a a4 pruebaDoc.doc > pruebaDoc.pdf
```

I get this message "The combination PDF and UTF-8 is not supported"

How can I fix this?

Comment: This question does not seem to fit at SO for me, it doesn't concern with programming problems.

Answer (score 1):

See [this post here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=191060#c1) for a Linux solution. This is the wrapper solution that they recommend:

```
#!/bin/sh

# a shell wrapper to make 'antiword' usage reasonable on UTF-8 systems.
#
# Michal Jaegermann, michal@harddata.com, 2004/Nov/03
#    - simplify and we may be printing on a Postcript printer, 2006/May/08

echo "$@" | egrep -q -w -- '-p|-a' && lang="${LANG%.UTF-8}"
LANG=$lang antiword.bin "$@"
exit
```

For Windows you can try specifying a specific mapping file using the `-m` switch:

```
antiword.exe -a a4 Test.doc -m 8859-1.txt > Test.pdf
```